# C# Console config renaming and relocating

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I am trying to figure out how to get this working.
I have a c# console application.
After build, the default config file I got is **myApp.exe.config**
I want to achieve the following:

1. I want to rename the config file to myApp.xml
2. I want to put it in a
   different location managed by some scheduling system.

I made it work by doing the following:

```
    private static void resetConfig()
    {
        var directory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var filename = $"{directory}\\myApp.xml";
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", filename);

            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                         BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, 0);

            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                            BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, null);

            typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                .Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.FullName ==
                            "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
                .First()
                .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                       BindingFlags.Static)
                .SetValue(null, null);
        }
    }
```

however, recently I upgraded some packages. And I got the following error while running it.

**Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SomePackage, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f3619abdd9aa739d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

The difference in config I noticed after upgrading the package is some new runtime section got added:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="SomePackage" publicKeyToken="f3619abdd9aa739d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.2.1.2" newVersion="6.2.1.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
```

Does anyone know how to fix the above error?

Comment: I do not think it is a great idea to rename your config file. It is a standard used by console applications. What is the reasoning behind this? If you want custom settings. Then I suggest you create a new myApp.xml and save your own settings there.

Comment: @KristianBarrett That is a requirement of the operation team, they have a central location to mange all sorts of config files, a lot of application are not written in c#, could be java, c++, python etc. So the agreed convention is to use .xml for all configs. And they may have a lot automation scripts running against the files which might break if it is not .xml

Comment: sure I understand. I would still argue that the things the operation team needs to know about and change can be outsource to your own .xml format. Instead of trying to force the .config file of your application into a XML file. The .config file is only there to describe the bare minimums of your application and what it needs to know to run it. Then you have an XML file. Lets call it operation-team.xml that contains server setups and environment etc.